# GWT GXT and Maven - 'Unable to find type'

Tags: gwt, maven, gxt

Using gxt and maven. I can get my project to compile and build a war file. But every time I try to run it using the codehaus gwt-maven-plugin plugin (gwt:run) I get:

```
Finding entry point classes
[ERROR] Unable to find type 'com.vetrado.admin.GxtProjectA
```

This is the EntryPoint class. This class is compiled and is on the classpath. But reading the GWT docs it says the source should also be on the classpath so GWT can compile it to javascript (makes sence). 
The question is, how do I put the source on the classpath of `gwt-maven-plugin` plugin?

```
  <plugin>
    <groupId>org.codehaus.mojo</groupId>
    <artifactId>gwt-maven-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.4.0</version>

    <executions>
      <execution>
        <goals>
          <goal>compile</goal>
        </goals>
      </execution>
    </executions>

    <configuration>
      <runTarget>GxtProjectA.html</runTarget>
    </configuration>
  </plugin>
```

Any ideas please?

Answer (score 0):

I have experienced some problems too with gwt-maven-plugin 2.4.0. The only solution which was working for me was downgrading to version 2.2.0.